# Incomplete npm private package installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am trying to install a private dependency and I am getting strange behavior. The entry point of this package I want to install is `"main": "src/index.js"`.

1. If I clone the whole repository and use it as a local dependency like this:

   *`package.json`*

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     ...
     "pkgName": "file:path/to/pkgName"
   }
   ```

   In the *`node_modules`* i get something similar to:

   ```
   pkgName
   ├── README.md
   ├── package.json
   └── src
       ├── index.js
       ├── file1.js
       ├── file2.js
       └── file3.js
   ```
2. But if I install it from my company's bitbucket like this:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     ...
     "pkgName": "git+https://user:password@bitbucket.org/companyName/pkgName.git"
   }
   ```

   What I get in *`node_modules`* is something like:

   ```
   pkgName
   ├── README.md
   ├── package.json
   └── src
       ├── index.js
       └── file1.js
   ```

In both cases the installation is successfully finished but in the last one **there are some files missing**.

Do you know what could be happening?

---

I have installed:

- npm 6.14.4
- node 14.16.1